# Problems in converting raster to vector in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to convert some raster layers (from a wms) to vector layers, by using the Polygonize tool in QGIS3.14, however I always get this decoding error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 41: invalid start byte

I even tried some other sample rasters but the same errormessage was given.
Is there any suggestion of what I can do to solve this problem?

I hope that somebody can help me

Comment: A WMS returns a picture of your data not your data, it is not a raster

Comment: Is there any way of saving the WMS picture as a raster in QGIS3?

Comment: No, a WMS is a **picture** if you want the data you need to use a WFS or a WCS service